# Ubuntu 18.04.3 doesn't recognize 2. montor after running these commands

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors

I executed these commands:

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"

sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"

sudo update-initramfs -u

sudo reboot
```

But  after rebooting, my 2. monitor is black and Ubuntu is not able to detect it. I went to Settings->Devices->Display and now I can only see my main monitor and not my second. Before running these commands, everything worked.

**How can I redo this?**

I ran this commands in reference to [this](https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/running-hashcat-on-ubuntu-18-04-server-with-1080ti/) post.

Maybe important:

- GPU: NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti
- Main monitor is plugged in with HDMI
- Second monitor is plugged in with DVI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert)!

This command solved my problem:

```
sudo sh -c 'rm -f /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf && update-initramfs -u && reboot'
```